# Javascript queryselector.style.modify "uncaught TypeError"

Tags: javascript, css, selectors-api

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ypos,sH,sH6,sIMG,sH4,sP;
        function trigger(){
        ypos=window.pageYOffset;
        /*..............................................Second page...*/
        sH=document.querySelector("#second h2");
        sH6=document.querySelector("#second h6");
        sIMG=document.querySelectorAll("#second img");
        sH4=document.querySelectorAll("#second h4");
        sP=document.querySelectorAll("#second p");
        /*.....................................Second page trigger...*/

        console.log(ypos);
            sH.style.opacity=0;
            if(ypos>120){ 
            sH.style.opacity=1;
            sH.style.transition="3s";
        };
            sH6.style.opacity=0;
            if(ypos>200){ 
            sH6.style.opacity=1;
            sH6.style.transition="3s";
        };
            sIMG.style.opacity=0;
            if(ypos>320){ 
            sIMG.style.opacity=1;
            sIMG.style.transition="3s";
        };
            sH4.style.opacity=0;
            if(ypos>400){ 
            sH4.style.opacity=1;
            sH4.style.transition="3s";
        };
            sP.style.opacity=0;
            if(ypos>480){ 
            sP.style.opacity=1;
            sP.style.transition="3s";
        };

        };

     window.addEventListener("scroll",trigger);
    </script>
```

When I try to modify "style" I get error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined

I find out that is node list, I was trying to add[0] because its a first element, but with no luck. How to define a object?

I usually use ID's but now I have lot of elements to animate.

I am new to javascript and I don't know how to use jQuery

Comment: When you use `querySelectorAll`, it always returns nodelist or say HTML collection. Use a loop to apply style to all elements which are selected or use `index`(`[0]/[1]/....`) to apply style to specific element.

Comment: Answer from @isvforall was good. I don't know why he removes it.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude because *I find out that is node list*: OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList), you need iterate over it

So for getting first element you can via `[0]`

```
sIMG[0].style
```

---

But [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) doesn't return [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList), it returns the first matching element. Here you don't need get first element via `[0]`

```
sH[0].style.opacity=0;  
// ^-- error here
```

It should be:

```
sH.style.opacity=0;
```

Comment: _I find out that is node list_: __OP__

Comment: @RayonDabre but in the code he didn't it...

Comment: It is possible that he wants to apply style to all the elements..It is better to sure before posting an answer....No hard feelings ;)

Comment: I tried to add sIMG[0].style but again the same error occur

Comment: @JovanLazarevic can you show updated code, need more info... it's hard to say...

Comment: sH=document.querySelector("#second h2); sH[0].style.opacity=0;    if(ypos>120){ 
       sH[0].style.opacity=1;
    sH[0].style.transition="3s";
   };

Comment: @JovanLazarevic see update